# Efficient (a XOR (b+1)) known (a XOR b) in C for the ChaCha algorithm

Tags: performance, algorithm, c

I'm currently trying to improve my ChaCha algorithm implementation. Here's the my code (written in C):

```
#include <string.h> // memcpy
#include <stddef.h> // size_t
#include <stdint.h> // uint32_t

typedef uint32_t ChaChaSigma [4];
typedef uint32_t ChaChaKey [8];
typedef uint32_t ChaChaNonce [4];
typedef enum ChaChaStandard {
    kOriginal,
    kIetf
} ChaChaStandard;
typedef short ChaChaRounds;
typedef uint32_t ChaChaBlock [16];

typedef struct ChaChaMatrix {
    union {
        struct {
            ChaChaSigma sigma; // The costant used. Usually "expand 32-byte k".
            ChaChaKey key;     // The key used. Has to be hashed or padded by the user manually.
            ChaChaNonce nonce; // The nonce used. It's formed by a block counter and an iv.
        };
        uint32_t words [16];   // The words of the matrix. Used for raw access.
    };
    ChaChaStandard standard;
    ChaChaRounds rounds;
} ChaChaMatrix;

// trick to have default values
#define INIT_CHACHAMATRIX(...) ((ChaChaMatrix){ \
    .sigma = {0x61707865UL, 0x3320646eUL, 0x79622d32UL, 0x6b206574UL}, \
    .key = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, \
    .nonce = {0, 0, 0, 0}, \
    .standard = kOriginal, \
    .rounds = 20, \
    __VA_ARGS__ \
})

uint32_t rotl32 (uint32_t n, short r) {
    return (n << r) | (n >> (32 - r));
}

void ChaChaStep (uint32_t x[16], size_t a, size_t b, size_t c, short r) {
    x[a] += x[b];
    x[c] = rotl32(x[c] ^ x[a], r);
}

void ChaChaQuarterRound (uint32_t x[16], size_t a, size_t b, size_t c, size_t d) {
    ChaChaStep(x, a, b, d, 16);
    ChaChaStep(x, c, d, b, 12);
    ChaChaStep(x, a, b, d,  8);
    ChaChaStep(x, c, d, b,  7);
}

void ChaChaVerticalRound (uint32_t x[16]) {
    ChaChaQuarterRound(x, 0, 4,  8, 12);
    ChaChaQuarterRound(x, 1, 5,  9, 13);
    ChaChaQuarterRound(x, 2, 6, 10, 14);
    ChaChaQuarterRound(x, 3, 7, 11, 15);
}

void ChaChaDiagonalRound (uint32_t x[16]) {
    ChaChaQuarterRound(x, 0, 5, 10, 15);
    ChaChaQuarterRound(x, 1, 6, 11, 12);
    ChaChaQuarterRound(x, 2, 7,  8, 13);
    ChaChaQuarterRound(x, 3, 4,  9, 14);
}

void ChaChaComputeBlock (ChaChaMatrix * matrix, ChaChaBlock * block) {
    memcpy(block, matrix, sizeof(uint32_t)*16);
    short i;
    for (i = 0; i < matrix->rounds; i+=2) {
        ChaChaVerticalRound(*block);
        ChaChaDiagonalRound(*block);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        (*block)[i] += matrix->words[i];
    }
}
```

I'm still planning an implementation to increase the counter without having to deal with type cast and IETF/Original standards.

The second action performed on the matrix uses the variable part (the block counter, inside the nonce). Because this (usually) increases only by 1 unit every time I was wondering if there's a way to improve its XOR efficency.

I opened excel and plotted a grpah of `BITXOR(314, i)`, `i` being the variable going from 0 to 999. The graph shows a nice pattern. Every `0x100*n` (in other words: every 4 "big downward steps" by `0x40` units) it jumps. The pattern is similar to the `XOR(0, ..., n)` one (?)

[image: graph]

My question are:

- Are there some efficient ways to calculate `a XOR (b+1)` known `a XOR b`? The pattern, to me, suggests that it might be possible, but I'm not smart enough to find a solution...
- Does it make sense to implement this tiny improvement?

PS: if the software engegneering stackexchange better fits the question format I can move it there :)

Comment: I don't think that 1. it is possible, as you cannot magic the possible carry out of nothing and 2. that it would make any difference.

Comment: Inlining the functions rotl32 and ChaChaStep  would allow some compiler optimizations for a small speed improvement.

Comment: There's `(a ^ (b + 1)) == (a ^ b) ^ (b ^ (b + 1))` to compute that thing from the "previous" thing, but that's worse. It's hard to compete with 2 operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A small review

> trying to improve my ChaCha algorithm implementation

**`static` function**

`rotl32()` is not a well defined function for rotating when the count is 0 (or 32).  That does not matter here as `rotl32(n, 0)` is not used.  Since the function is only correct for local usage, make it `static` to avoid other modules using this reduced purpose function.

```
// uint32_t rotl32 (uint32_t n, short r) {
static uint32_t rotl32 (uint32_t n, short r) {
```

**Avoid magic numbers**

Why 16 below? Why `uint32_t`?.  One could look around code and eventuality see what `memcpy()` is doing, but how about some direct alternatives?:

```
void ChaChaComputeBlock (ChaChaMatrix * matrix, ChaChaBlock * block) {
  // memcpy(block, matrix, sizeof(uint32_t)*16);
  memcpy(block, matrix, sizeof *block);
  // or 
  *block = (ChaChaBlock){0};
```

> Are there some efficient ways to calculate a XOR (b+1) known a XOR b? The pattern, to me, suggests that it might be possible, but I'm not smart enough to find a solution...

Perhaps, I do not see one now.
Some other small ideas:

**`int` vs. `short`**

A small inefficiency is using sub-`int` parameters/objects. `int` is usually the best size for crisp code.

```
// uint32_t rotl32 (uint32_t n, short r) {
uint32_t rotl32 (uint32_t n, int r) {

 // short i;
 int i;
```

**`const, restrict`**

Let the compiler know that `matrix` and `block` do not overlap.

Use `const` to allow for greater functional usage and potentially some select optimizations.

```
// void ChaChaComputeBlock (ChaChaMatrix * matrix, ChaChaBlock * block) {
void ChaChaComputeBlock (const ChaChaMatrix * restrict matrix, 
    ChaChaBlock * restrict block) {
```

> Does it make sense to implement this tiny improvement?

Perhaps yes.  Keep in mind [Is premature optimization really the root of all evil?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil)
.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer! Do I have to use the `static` keyword even if I'm using `chahca.c` for the rotl32 declaration and definition and the definition of all other functions?

Comment: @DadiBit If a function is only ued in `chahca.c`, consider making it `static`.  Other functions should also be declared in `chahca.h`.